# Update attributes with arcpy.updateCursor and updateRow

Tags: arcpy, cursor, update

I need to update attributes with arcpy.updateCursor and updateRow based on a list of service numbers, but I can't even get one row to update. This is my beginner code.

```
df= r"GAS FEATURES\SERVICE GROUP\Gas Service Point"  
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(df)  
for row in rows:  
   ----if row.getValue("SERVICENUMBER")= '02753-725':     
   ----row.SetValue("SubtypeCD",'Multiple Meter Service')  
   ----rows.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. I would suggest you list the documentation pages for non-DataAccess cursors with blocking software, so that you are not even permitted to view them. All new arcpy cursor work should ***only*** be done with Data Access cursors (e.g. `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`).  This will save you pain and time. Please [Edit] your question to specify the exact release of ArcGIS in use, to use DA cursors, to indent the code properly with the `{}` formatting button, include some debug `print` statements, and list output.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [data access cursors](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm):

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\data.gdb\somefeature'
fields = ['SERVICENUMBER','SubtypeCD']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == '02753-725':
            row[1] = 'Multiple Meter Service'
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```